# Injected service is undefined right in the constructor

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-injection

For the note, I'm quite uninitiated to Angular (1 or 2 for that matter).

I'm trying to write a "super" layer of Http to avoid having to put the same headers everywhere.

```
import {Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {LoadingService} from "../../services/loading.service";

export class HttpLoading extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
        private _ls: LoadingService )
    {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    getPostPutHeader() {
        var authHeader = new Headers();
        authHeader.append("Authorization", "Bearer "+ localStorage.getItem('token') );
        authHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return authHeader;
    }

    post(url: string, data:any):Observable<Response> {
        this._ls.isLoading = true; // Exception here: this._ls is undefined
        return super.post(url, data, { headers: this.getPostPutHeader() })
            .map(res => {
                this._ls.isLoading = false;
                return res;
            });
    }
}
```

And a service to tell when a request is executing; it's injected in the above class HttpLoading.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
    isLoading: boolean = false;
}
```

I have a bunch of stuff in my bootstrap, including HttpLoading, LoadingService and ConnectionBackend (for this last one, I get an exception if it's not here).

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ConnectionBackend,
    HttpLoading,
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    LoadingService,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
])
```

The problem is that the first time I call `HttpLoading`'s `post` method (in yet another service), I get an exception at `this._ls.isLoading`, because `this._ls` is undefined, and I can't figure why.

Please tell me if you need more information.

---

Edit

`LoadingService` is correctly injected in my `AppComponent` (main component).

```
//imports
//@Component
export class AppComponent {
    requesting:boolean = false;

    constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private _ls: LoadingService) {
    }

    navigate(route:string) {
        this._ls.isLoading = true;
        this.router.navigate([route])
            .then(() => this._ls.isLoading = false);
    }
}
```

---

Potential solution

It seems that your public/private parameters must be placed first in the list. I'll let someone more skilled than me explain why, though...

```
export class HttpLoading extends Http {

    constructor(private _ls: LoadingService, backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would configure your `HttpLoading` class this way in the providers when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  (...)
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  {
    provide:Http,
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, loadingService: LoadingService) => {
      return new HttpLoading(backend, defaultOptions, loadingService);
    },
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, LoadingService]
  }
]);
```

The reason for this is that you want to use your own class for the Http provider. You need to change the class behind the Http provider by your `HttpLoading` class. Be careful to define it after `HTTP_PROVIDERS`.

To be able to inject the instance of `XHRBackend` to your class, you need to use `useFactory`...

Comment: Could you please explain why, if that's not too much of a hassle? Also I think you're missing a closing curly bracket; I have an error in my IDE

Comment: I added some explanations in my answer... Feel free to tell me if it answers your question... Otherwise, you're right. A `{` needed to be removed ;-) Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still don't understand everything, but that's a start! Does that "replace" automatically Http with HttpLoading when I use Http in my components? And should I replace ConnectionBackend with XHRBackend in HttpLoading's constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I know that may seem trivial, but try to create a variable and initialize it in the constructor

Comment: I also recommend this -- the optimization engine may be removing the reference to this dependency.

Comment: Besides I don't see how  it would make it work, this couldn't be a solution at any level. A service injected in the constructor, should always be available inside the underlying context.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Thierry Templier's answer. I am using Angular v4, and my experience is that you need to provide ALL the dependencies that your extending constructor needs, AND in the right order - I guess it's a legacy way of doing it, from angular 1.x.

My example:

// This is my extended class (relevant part only)

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

    constructor(
        backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions,

        private router: Router,
        private loaderService: LoaderService,
        private modalService: ModalService,
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    )
    {
        super(backend, defaultOptions)
    }
```

// This is the provider factory defined in app.module.ts:

```
export function httpClientFactory(
        backend: XHRBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
        router: Router,
        loaderService: LoaderService,
        modalService: ModalService,
        localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) : Http
{
    return new HttpService(
        backend,
        defaultOptions,
        router,
        loaderService,
        modalService,
        localStorageService
    );
}
```

This is the configuration (just left the relevant part) in app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
    ModalService
    LocalStorageService,
    LoaderService,
    {
        provide: HttpService,
        useFactory: httpClientFactory,
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, LoaderService, ModalService, LocalStorageService]
    }
```

Note: notice the order of declaring the deps in the config compared to the factory constructor .. it is the same